# Can't run gradle on jenkins slave

Tags: hudson, jenkins, gradle

I've configured a jenkins ubuntu slave and I want to run my gradle build on it(with gradle plugin). The problem is that when running the jenkins build job I get:

```
 $ gradle --no-daemon --info clean build
 FATAL: command execution failed
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gradle" (in directory "/var/jenkins/workspace/dadi"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
```

When running the same gradle command on the command line of the slave(same user) it runs successfully.

Comment: Ok, another try: did you set `GRAILS_HOME` variable on the slave?

Comment: I guess you mean GRADLE_HOME. in that case I did set it both on the slave and in the jenkins node configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a workaround solution!
I've start using gradle wrapper in order to run the gradle build.
I did 2 things:

1. followed instructions on this [page](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) to create gradlew (and other files) and checked them in my repository
2. in jenkins gradle plugin marked the build step to use gradle wrapper.

   `task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
      gradleVersion = '2.0'
   }`

This above line would create`.gradle` folder & download required `gradle` version(mentioned in the task) every time gradle build is run, that means there is **no need to check-in .gradle folder** into your repository anymore.

Also had to rename gradlew to gradle.bat since the jenkins gradle plugin try to run the gradle.bat even on linux.
That's it. working.

Comment: This is a problem with the Jenkins gradle plugin.  One should not have to check in gradlew files into the upstream repo...